# How to do slow motion effect in flash game with box2d

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

As i am working on top view racing game in which am trying to add slow motion effect when a car hits objects. I have tried with decreasing **Stage.frameRate** but the game appears lagging. and i have also tried with online tutorial called ***touch my pixel*** ( ref : http://blog.touchmypixel.com/2009/12/box2d-contactpoint-filtering/ ). But i didn't understand.

Is there any solution for showing such kind of **slow motion** effect. can anybody help me in this regard

Thanks and regards,

Chandrasekhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to have a global modifier property somewhere which can be used to multiply the movement of everything in the game.

For example, you could have the property `speedModifier` default to `1`.

```
public var speedModifier:Number = 1;
```

And whenever you apply velocities, just multiply by the modifier:

```
body.SetLinearVelocity( new b2Vec2(x * speedModifier, y * speedModifier) );
```

This way all you need to do to half the speed of the game is to half the modifier:

```
speedModifier = 0.5;
```

---

To keep your code tidier and make managing this component of your game easier, there is probably a straightforward way to iterate over all of the bodies within the Box2D world and modify their velocities at the top of each update step. Something along the lines of:

```
for each(var i:b2Body in world.GetBodyList())
{
    var currentVel:b2Vec2 = i.GetLinearVelocity();

    var newVel:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(
        currentVel.x * speedModifier,
        currentVel.y * speedModifier
    );

    i.SetLinearVelocity( newVel );
}
```